# element.focus() differs in Firefox&Edge vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a long angular form on my page, and on form submit if something is invalid, I call .focus() on the invalid input element. I also have a top navigation on the same page, and my content is scrolled under the navigation during page scrolling.

The problem is, that Chrome's behavior is that it scrolls the input element into the (approximately) middle of the page, so it's visible, but Edge & Firefox only scrolls it until the element is present on the page, but the top navigation hides it. Is there a way to make this thing behave like it behaves in Chrome?

Comment: I have experienced a similar thing and solved by calculating where the element is, and using the `window`'s`scroll` and `scrollTo` methods. Not supported in IE or Safari, though. Although, it'd be interesting to see what other solutions you've _already tried_ to overcome this?

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but that didn't look that much professional. But I'll stick to this, if there is no other solution.

Comment: I solved it via  invalidControl.scrollIntoView(false);

Basically it solved my issue, but the fact that it's using bottom-align can cause problems in some cases, but not in mine.